# Blackberry MainScreen doesn't scroll smoothly

Tags: blackberry, scroll, focus

This only happens on non-touch BB devices e.g. Bold

I have a MainScreen and I add a LabelField with very long text (doesn't fit within the display's height). Below I add a ButtonField.

Now when I try to scroll, it doesn't scroll, instead it jumps to the ButtonField. So it is impossible to read the whole text in the LabelField.

I cannot split the text in the LabelField, because I get it dynamically and it might be one paragraph without linebreaks. Even without a period (german sentences can be very long).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use field style `FOCUSABLE`. 
If it doesn't help try to use `RichTextField`.

Comment: On OS 5 `FOCUSABLE` will do no good. Read only `RichTextField` will do the job.

Comment: Read only `RichTextField` will do the job.

Comment: That was easy. Thanks. RichTextField does the job perfectly.